# OSX freezes and logs me out when switching workspaces, it doesn't happen everytime and it's not consistant?

Tags: high-sierra, performance, logs, spaces

[image]

I'm running OSX High Sierra 10.13.2.

also,

where can I collect more info about why this is happening?

Comment: Only time I've ever had that happen is running out of memory using OpenGL. Are you running anything that uses it? Photoshop etc do.

Comment: How are you switching workspaces?

Comment: I usually run xcode, ios simulator , another editor, a few other apps and my browser(s), I didn't think they'd 16G of ram , I will definitely keep an eye on memory consumption from now on , Thanks @Tetsujin.

Comment: @Mark 4 finger swift or command shift ( left|right arrows ) .

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you are actually correct, I just checked the memory usage and I'm consuming 13G of ram ...

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm still having this issue, I tracked the logs this time,
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314657/macos-freezes-for-a-few-seconds-then-logsout