# MacOS freezes for a few seconds then logout?

Tags: macos, fast-user-switching

This question is related to one I asked before,

[OSX freezes and logs me out when switching workspaces, it doesn't happen everytime and it's not consistant?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312261/osx-freezes-and-logs-me-out-when-switching-workspaces-it-doesnt-happen-everyti)

I did track the logs this time but it is a bit cryptic for me to go through, ( actually I have no idea what they mean at all ).

Those are the logs while it was working up to it froze, maybe a little when it was actually frozen (`••My__Mac••` is the name of my Mac):

```
Feb  6 16:13:29 192 Memory Purge[4693]: [error] Connection failed. Server error., not found
Feb  6 16:13:29 192 Memory Purge[4693]: [info] Status was: 404
Feb  6 16:13:29 192 Memory Purge[4693]: [info] ATAPIRequest failed: Server error., not found
Feb  6 16:13:45 192 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.WindowServer[4368]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 sent by exc handler[0]
Feb  6 16:13:46 192 sessionlogoutd[13366]: DEAD_PROCESS: 4367 console
Feb  6 16:13:46 192 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.auditd[13367]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.auditd
Feb  6 16:13:46 192 aeid[13372]: audit warning: soft /var/audit
Feb  6 16:13:46 192 aeid[13371]: audit warning: allsoft
Feb  6 16:13:46 192 aeid[13374]: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20180206130416.20180206131346
Feb  6 16:13:48 ••My__Mac•• findmydeviced[13376]: objc[13376]: Class LocalizedUnregisterErrorKey is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FindMyDevice.framework/Versions/A/FindMyDevice (0x7fffacc57080) and /usr/libexec/findmydeviced (0x102eec5c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.gamed[4750]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.gamed[4750]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.akd[4470]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.akd[4470]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.cloudphotosd[4433]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.cloudphotosd[4433]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesd[4756]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesd[4756]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.fontd[4463]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.fontd[4463]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsurlstoraged[4480]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsurlstoraged[4480]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CalendarAgent[4428]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CalendarAgent[4428]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.suggestd[4495]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.suggestd[4495]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.commerce[4484]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.commerce[4484]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.storeassetd[4703]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.storeassetd[4703]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.photoanalysisd[4436]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.photoanalysisd[4436]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.cloudd[4453]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.cloudd[4453]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.accountsd[4440]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.accountsd[4440]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.mozilla.firefox.21244[4858]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd[4474]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.corespotlightd[4435]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.halfbits.MemoryFree.21304[4693]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.contacts.donation-agent[4871]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.diagnostics_agent[4545]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mongodb[4534]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Spotlight[4469]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.github.atom.21192.41F96A31-60E1-43D4-B221-9E853DCF9B3B[8919]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql[4536]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.photolibraryd[4497]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Dock.agent[4447]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.google.Chrome.21264[5146]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.postgresql[4540]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.rapportd[4423]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:51 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.usernoted[4425]): Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:52 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Dock.agent[4447]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Feb  6 16:13:52 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Spotlight[4469]): Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15 sent by launchd[1]
Feb  6 16:13:53 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.halfbits.MemoryFree.21304[4693]): Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15 sent by launchd[1]
Feb  6 16:13:54 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.mozilla.firefox.21244[4858]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:54 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.mozilla.firefox.21244[4858]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:54 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.corespotlightd[4435]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:54 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.corespotlightd[4435]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:54 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.github.atom.21192.41F96A31-60E1-43D4-B221-9E853DCF9B3B[8919]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:54 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.github.atom.21192.41F96A31-60E1-43D4-B221-9E853DCF9B3B[8919]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
Feb  6 16:13:54 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.google.Chrome.21264[5146]): Service did not exit 3 seconds after SIGKILL.
Feb  6 16:13:54 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.google.Chrome.21264[5146]): Abandoning service instance. This may lead to deadlocks.
```

this is while it was freezing:

```
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): Could not import service from caller: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.PCIESlotCheck.plist, caller = loginwindow.13375, error = 138: Service cannot be loaded on this hardware
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): Caller tried to import service with same label as an existing service: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.pluginkit.pkd.plist, caller = loginwindow.13375
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.protectedcloudstorage.protectedcloudkeysyncing (lint): Invalid type for a LaunchEvent (stream/name/type): com.apple.ProtectedCloudStorage.daily/Interval/int64
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.protectedcloudstorage.protectedcloudkeysyncing (lint): Invalid type for a LaunchEvent (stream/name/type): com.apple.ProtectedCloudStorage.daily/Priority/string
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.PubSub.Agent): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.ReportCrash.Self (lint): DrainMessagesOnCrash is not yet implemented. If you rely on this key, please file a bug.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.ReportCrash (lint): DrainMessagesOnCrash is not yet implemented. If you rely on this key, please file a bug.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.routined): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.routined): Unknown key for Boolean: EnabledPressuredExit
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.sharingd): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.soagent (lint): Invalid type for a LaunchEvent (stream/name/type): ichat/events/array
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.soagent (lint): Invalid type for a LaunchEvent (stream/name/type): ichat/bundleid/string
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): Caller tried to import service with same label as an existing service: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.storeinstallagent.plist, caller = loginwindow.13375
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  6 16:14:43 --- last message repeated 6 times ---
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.tiswitcher (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): Caller tried to import service with same label as an existing service: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.trustd.agent.plist, caller = loginwindow.13375
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.universalaccesscontrol (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.universalaccessd (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.usernoted): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.VoiceOver (lint): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Feb  6 16:14:43 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100269.Aqua): com.apple.warmd_agent (lint): Assuming EnablePressuredExit=false given EnableTransactions=false.
Feb  6 16:14:44 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Feb  6 16:14:44 ••My__Mac•• UserEventAgent[13423]: objc[13423]: Class NPUtilities is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkServiceProxy.framework/Versions/A/NetworkServiceProxy (0x7fffada81cb0) and /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.netsvcproxy.plugin/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.netsvcproxy (0x10a67c6b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:44 ••My__Mac•• UserEventAgent[13423]: objc[13423]: Class NSPConnectionInfo is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkServiceProxy.framework/Versions/A/NetworkServiceProxy (0x7fffada81d78) and /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.netsvcproxy.plugin/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.netsvcproxy (0x10a67c7a8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:44 ••My__Mac•• networkserviceproxy[13435]: objc[13435]: Class NSPFlowDivert is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkServiceProxy.framework/Versions/A/NetworkServiceProxy (0x7fffada81e40) and /usr/libexec/networkserviceproxy (0x10e1cc938). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:44 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Feb  6 16:14:47 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  6 16:14:47 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.postgresql): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Feb  6 16:14:49 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Feb  6 16:14:52 ••My__Mac•• xpcproxy[13470]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Feb  6 16:14:53 ••My__Mac•• aeid[13479]: audit warning: soft /var/audit
Feb  6 16:14:53 ••My__Mac•• aeid[13480]: audit warning: allsoft
Feb  6 16:14:53 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Feb  6 16:14:54 ••My__Mac•• Spotlight[13481]: objc[13481]: Class SPWebHistoryResult is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Spotlight.framework/Versions/A/Spotlight (0x7fffaf085150) and /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight (0x10eac7b30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:54 ••My__Mac•• Spotlight[13481]: objc[13481]: Class SPWebHistoryQuery is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Spotlight.framework/Versions/A/Spotlight (0x7fffaf085128) and /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight (0x10eac7b80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:54 ••My__Mac•• Spotlight[13481]: objc[13481]: Class SPDefaults is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Spotlight.framework/Versions/A/Spotlight (0x7fffaf084db8) and /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight (0x10eac7ec8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:54 ••My__Mac•• Spotlight[13481]: objc[13481]: Class SPShortcutPattern is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Spotlight.framework/Versions/A/Spotlight (0x7fffaf0859e8) and /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight (0x10eac8198). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:54 ••My__Mac•• Spotlight[13481]: objc[13481]: Class SPLogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Spotlight.framework/Versions/A/Spotlight (0x7fffaf084f70) and /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight (0x10eac8418). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:54 ••My__Mac•• Spotlight[13481]: objc[13481]: Class SPLoggingSearchSession is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Spotlight.framework/Versions/A/Spotlight (0x7fffaf0858f8) and /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight (0x10eac8440). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:54 ••My__Mac•• Spotlight[13481]: objc[13481]: Class SPAppDefaults is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Spotlight.framework/Versions/A/Spotlight (0x7fffaf084cc8) and /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight (0x10eac84b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:55 ••My__Mac•• backgroundtaskmanagementagent[13484]: objc[13484]: Class BTMLoginItem is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Versions/A/BackgroundTaskManagement (0x7fffabc20558) and /System/Library/CoreServices/backgroundtaskmanagementagent (0x105e883d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:55 ••My__Mac•• backgroundtaskmanagementagent[13484]: objc[13484]: Class BTMBackgroundItem is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Versions/A/BackgroundTaskManagement (0x7fffabc204e0) and /System/Library/CoreServices/backgroundtaskmanagementagent (0x105e88568). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb  6 16:14:56 ••My__Mac•• aeid[13487]: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20180206131422.20180206131453
Feb  6 16:14:57 ••My__Mac•• com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
```

It'd be great if some one could take a look at any suspicious stuff that I could research further.

Answer (score -1):

I can only tell you that you're not alone. I've got similar symptoms and I've got a case opened w/ Apple. The make me try all kinds of things but I'm positive it's a software problem. And it's not even the two of us. See https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/73xxz3/macos_high_sierra_always_freezing/ ja https://discussions.apple.com/message/32366001?ac_cid=tw123456&replyId=32366001#32366001 or  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8204124 or https://myapple.pl/forums/topic/331181-mbp15-2014-a1398/

Comment: after I stopped using workspaces, it rarely crashes.